# How to alert a user before re-directing them to another page?

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a session where the user is required to be logged in before accessing a page. Essentially I want them to be alerted that they need to be logged in before re-directing them to the login page.

```
<html>
    <body>

        <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
            $username = $_SESSION['username'];
            echo "<p>Username: $username</p>\n";
        } else {    
            header('Location: login_home.html');
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Please login to view this page')</script>";
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

At the moment it is just re-directing without alerting any information.

Comment: outputting before header

Comment: This does — not — work. You must — not — have output before the `header`.

Comment: As mentioned in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You can't redirect with php `header()` and have output before. This is because, as the name said, it will redirect the user only be the HTTP Header. So this will happens before the rendering of the browsers content and will throw an error by php, if you had output before calling `header()`.

But you could simply redirect using javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    alert('Please login to view this page');
    window.location.replace('login_home.html');
</script>
```

Comment: Would each line need to be echo'd if it is in PHP markers?

Comment: For a more detailed post regarding `window.location.href` see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/506004/6009304). It's basically explains `replace` vs `href` and what is the better solution for a basic scenario.

Comment: @Thomas you can combine the echo statements into 1. Either concatenate each line together or just wrap the entire block with double quotes. I personally prefer concatenating the lines. Ultimately it will have to be echoed or be placed in a JavaScript file/script block.

Comment: You could write this in one line, as you did in the question, too. I just used multiple lines for better readability. @Thomas

Comment: I've put 

       echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Please login to view this page'); window.location.href = 'login_home.html'; </script>";  

but it still seems to just re-direct with no alert?

Comment: And @Tyler has a good point here, `replace` is the better choice, regarding your initial question. But both, `replace` and `href` will work.